# In AWS Redshift Serverless is there a svl_udf_log table or view ? If No what is the alternative?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

My fundamental question is, how to debug a UDF in Redshift serverless environment?  SQL clients suggest to use svl_udf_log  but I do not find that.